# TransientObjectException when saving a Map attribute in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, persistence

I'm getting the following error when looking up a persisted object which has a `Map` attribute:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: [package].MapKey; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: [package].MapKey
```

Most explanations I found refer to adding `CascadeType.ALL`, which I have done.

The error appears only when I execute a custom query, not with the `findById` method:

```
EntityWithMap saved = service.save(entity);
    
assertEquals(entity.getMap(), service.findById(saved.getId()).get().getMap()); //No error

assertEquals(entity.getMap(), service.findByName("test entity").get(0).getMap()); //InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException
```

EntityWithMap:

```
@Entity
public class EntityWithMap {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "mapping_mapkey_mapvalue", 
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "value_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "entity_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "key_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Map<MapKey, MapValue> map = new HashMap<>();

    private String name;
    
    public EntityWithMap(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Map<MapKey, MapValue> getMap() {
        return map;
    }
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void addToMap(MapKey key, MapValue value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }
    
}
```

MapKey:

```
@Entity
public class MapKey {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
}
```

MapValue:

```
@Entity
public class MapValue {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
}
```

Test class:

```
@DataJpaTest
@Import(EntityWithMapService.class)
public class PersistMappingTest {

    @Autowired private EntityWithMapService service;
    
    @Test
    public void testPersistence() {
        
        EntityWithMap entity = new EntityWithMap("test entity");
        entity.addToMap(new MapKey(), new MapValue());
        entity.addToMap(new MapKey(), new MapValue());
        entity.addToMap(new MapKey(), new MapValue());

        EntityWithMap saved = service.save(entity);
        
        assertEquals(entity.getMap(), service.findById(saved.getId()).get().getMap()); //No error

        assertEquals(entity.getMap(), service.findByName("test entity").get(0).getMap()); //InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException
    }
}
```

EntityWithMapService:

```
@Service
public class EntityWithMapService {

    private EntityWithMapRepository repository;

    public EntityWithMapService(EntityWithMapRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public EntityWithMap save(EntityWithMap entity) {
        return repository.save(entity);
    }

    public Optional<EntityWithMap> findById(Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id);
    }
    
    public List<EntityWithMap> findByName(String name) {
        return repository.findByName(name);
    }
    
}
```

EntityWithMapRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface EntityWithMapRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityWithMap, Long> {
    
    @Query("FROM EntityWithMap e WHERE e.name = :name")
    public List<EntityWithMap> findByName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of things that seem to be off in your example.

1. Your test `PersistMappingTest` is trying to persist a record of `EntityWithMap` with references to instance of `MapKey` and `MapValue` without persisting them first. You need to persist the `MapKey` and `MapValue` records before you can use them as references in the `EntityWithMap` record. This might be the primary reason you get `TransientObjectException`.

Example (pseudo code):

```java
MapKey mapKey1 = mapKeyService.save(new MapKey());
MapKey mapKey2 = mapKeyService.save(new MapKey());
MapKey mapKey3 = mapKeyService.save(new MapKey());

MapValue mapValue1 = mapValueService.save(new MapValue());
MapValue mapValue2 = mapValueService.save(new MapValue());
MapValue mapValue3 = mapValueService.save(new MapValue());

EntityWithMap entity = new EntityWithMap("test entity");
entity.addToMap(mapKey1, mapValue1);
entity.addToMap(mapKey2, mapValue2);
entity.addToMap(mapKey3, mapValue3);
```

NOTE: if it's intentional to not persist the `MapKey` and `MapValue` map in the DB and it's only for in-memory use then, try adding the `@Transient` annotation to the map field in `EntityWithMap`.

2. You `MapValue` entity is not referencing `MapKey` at all. How can `MapKey` be the key of `MapValue` if `MapValue` is not aware of it.

Example (pseudo code):

```java
@Entity
public class MapValue {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mapkey_id")
    private MapKey mapKey;
    
}
```

3. You shouldn't need to create a new instance of `HashMap<>` in the declaration of the map in entity `EntityWithMap`. JPA should do that for you. This could also be a reason you get the exception.

Look at this article for more information:
https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-persisting-maps

Comment: won't CascadeType.ALL take care of persisting `MapKey` and `MapValue`?